# php-fpm php_network_getaddresses calls randomly start failing with bad udp cksum

Tags: amazon-web-services, php-fpm, udp

We're running a number of web servers (nginx, php5.6-fpm) on ubuntu instances on AWS. They've been running fine for a number of months, but in the past few days we've started getting issues where after an instance spins up everything is fine, but after 12 hours or so, network calls start to fail (specifically in this instance socket tcp calls to redis).

Having done some digging with tcpdump, it looks like the dns lookups are being thrown out because of a udp checksum failure:

17:13:38.013346 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 46236, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 103)
    10.0.0.121.34071 > 10.0.0.2.53: [bad udp cksum 0x14df -> 0x3ae1!] 25855+ Type20736? xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com. (75)

If I use telnet to connect to the Redis server from the same instance then it's fine, it only seems to affect fpm. Equally strange, it only happens a little while after the instance has started - initially all the requests go through fine. Equally, re-starting the php5.6-fpm service seems to clear the issue for a time.

I'm pretty much at the end of my knowledge at this point, so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: We just had this start happening to us last night. Reloading php7.1-fpm fixed it temporarily for us, it's started happening now again. Looking for the cause as well, as it doesn't seem like it will go away.

Comment: see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1674733

Comment: @ZdenekMachek That matches up with what we're seeing, will try and use those instructions. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, looks like this might be it - all our instances have had their libc upgraded now, so going to monitor it for the next few hours - fingers crossed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a defective security fix installed -- this sounds like the issue from [USN-3239-2](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3239-2/).

A security update for GNU libc that addressed (among other things)...

> an unbounded stack allocation in the `getaddrinfo()` function of the GNU C Library.

....contained a regression -- an unintended ABI change -- that seems to have caused issues similar to what you describe... DNS resolution would eventually stop working until processes were restarted.

The original update was release 2017-03-20 and the fix was released 2017-03-21.  Applying the latest OS security fixes should remedy the issue, if that's what this is.

Answer (score 0):

The bad checksums might be due to [checksum offloading](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Offloading).

I would check if that is the case, which you can do by running:

`sudo ethtool --show-offload ethX`

It may be worth digging a little further into what tcpdump might say about the *content* of your packets, though - notably, I would wonder whether you might not be hitting some kind of rate-limiting.
You may want to check return packets for `NXDOMAIN` or similar.

If that was the issue, having some kind of caching resolver might help.

**updated** to account for comments below:

If restarting the service itself is 'fixing' the issue (thanks @[Liam Wiltshire](https://serverfault.com/users/131532/liam-wiltshire) for the added info), then I agree that rate-limiting doesn't sound right (or at least, rate-limiting by the upstream doesn't).

I suppose rate-limiting due to local resources might still be a possibility worth considering: for example, ensuring there isn't a limit of conntrack entries, or `ulimit`'ed open files (ie. `nofiles` is to low.

That being said, the bad security patch/bad software lead does seem rather more promising -  so I would definitely give weight (and have given points) to @[Michael - sqlbot](https://serverfault.com/users/153161/michael-sqlbot)'s suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for this - yes, that's one of my suspects to - indeed we are offloading checksumming:

root@ip-10-0-2-220:~# ethtool --show-offload  ens3
Features for ens3:
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on


However, I'm a little confused as to why it'd be fine to start off with, and then start failing later on.

Comment: That pattern is what makes me suspect rate-limiting on your upstream DNS servers - couple with the fact the DNS requests do seem to be sent (if that was not the case, I would tend to suspect ulimits (nofiles in particular) or insufficient conntrack capacity.

Comment: I'll have to wait for the issue to happen again to test (unfortunately over night we had little choice than to spin up new instances to keep the site running!), and see if one of other of these are to blame. The only reason I question it being related to rate limiting is that if I restart php5.6-fpm, the issue goes away (at least for a time).

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue this was a good suggestion but I think the issue in this case may be related to a bad security patch released this week.  Solving the issue by restarting the process seems to rule out any kind of external rate limiting, and that's apparently the behavior this issue exhibits.